# Codename One Netbeans Plugin Version

Tags: codenameone

I updated the Codename One plugin in Netbeans from 3.5.6 to 3.5.7. There is a bug in the latest version which stops MultiButtons for working (#1954). Is there a way for me to remove the latest version and return to version 3.5.6 so I can carry on developing my app?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it seems it was broken because of (ironically) lead component support.

I'm guessing we'll need to release another update this Friday as it seems like an important bug fix. I'm not aware of any way to revert a netbeans plugin to an older version.